# Changing the primary key name in EF6

Tags: entity-framework-6, entity-framework-migrations, azure-mobile-services

When I make a migration file in Azure .Net Backend, it automatically generates the five required fields(Id,CreatedAt, UpdatedAt, Version, Deleted) with my customer fields. It defines Id as the primary key.

```
public override void Up()
    {
        CreateTable(
            "dbo.People",
            c => new
                {
                    Id = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 128,
                        annotations: new Dictionary<string, AnnotationValues>
                        {
                            { 
                                "ServiceTableColumn",
                                new AnnotationValues(oldValue: null, newValue: "Id")
                            },
                        }),
                    PersonType = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 2),
                    FirstName = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 50),
                    MiddleName = c.String(maxLength: 50),
                    LastName = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 50),
                    Gender = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 1),
                    BirthDate = c.DateTime(nullable: false, storeType: "date"),
                    Version = c.Binary(nullable: false, fixedLength: true, timestamp: true, storeType: "rowversion",
                        annotations: new Dictionary<string, AnnotationValues>
                        {
                            { 
                                "ServiceTableColumn",
                                new AnnotationValues(oldValue: null, newValue: "Version")
                            },
                        }),
                    CreatedAt = c.DateTimeOffset(nullable: false, precision: 7,
                        annotations: new Dictionary<string, AnnotationValues>
                        {
                            { 
                                "ServiceTableColumn",
                                new AnnotationValues(oldValue: null, newValue: "CreatedAt")
                            },
                        }),
                    UpdatedAt = c.DateTimeOffset(precision: 7,
                        annotations: new Dictionary<string, AnnotationValues>
                        {
                            { 
                                "ServiceTableColumn",
                                new AnnotationValues(oldValue: null, newValue: "UpdatedAt")
                            },
                        }),
                    Deleted = c.Boolean(nullable: false,
                        annotations: new Dictionary<string, AnnotationValues>
                        {
                            { 
                                "ServiceTableColumn",
                                new AnnotationValues(oldValue: null, newValue: "Deleted")
                            },
                        }),
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id)
            .Index(t => t.CreatedAt, clustered: true);

    }
```

I want to change this primary key name "Id" to "PersonId", so I add a primary key property like below

```
 public class Person : EntityData
{
    public string PersonId;
    ....
}
```

But it did not work. "Id" was not replaced by "PersonId" and just added as a customer field in the migration file. So, Added the [Key] attribute but it made an error and I got the below message.

"Unable to determine composite primary key ordering for type . Use the ColumnAttribute or the HasKey method to specify an order for composite primary keys."

How I can change the primary key name?

Comment: You should add migration code manually for renamed columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the HasKey method to set the property to be a primary Key.

For example,

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Person>().HasKey(t => t.PersonId);
```

It will set the PersonId as the primary key.

Good Luck.